# When re-tagging old threads, how many should one do at once?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing, etiquette

Sometimes we decide to take care of confusing tags and this involves manual re-tagging. We all agree that one should only start mass re-tagging old threads after it has been discussed & approved on Meta.

There is a broad consensus that one should not re-tag too many threads in one sitting, because all edited threads get pushed to the front page and can become overwhelming or annoying.

I have seen advice (I believe by @gung, @Glen_b, and others) to limit oneself to only a couple of questions (let's say 3-4) at a time. I know patient people (@AndreSilva) who always re-tag only one single question per day. Some others  tend to re-tag more. I have recently started to re-tag 10 questions at a time in order to see what people will think about it. I think it's good to discuss it.

**What should be the approximate upper number of questions that one should be allowed to re-tag in one sitting?**

This assumes that "sittings" are separated by at least half a day. It also assumes that this particular re-tagging action has been discussed & approved.

**Please upvote ONE SINGLE ANSWER from below. Please do not downvote any.**

Comment: Related discussion is in the comments to this answer http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/1625/28666.

Comment: I think when I did all the various `[fisher*]` tags, I did them 5 at a time.

Comment: Thanks, @gung. It seems that 5 is currently winning, but I'd like to get more opinions; hopefully more people will vote after the weekend.

Comment: I don't think it has to be a hard rule. 5 is more of a rule of thumb. I also don't necessarily think waiting half a day needs to be a hard rule. IMO, it's mostly about gaging what won't be disruptive.

Comment: @gung, of course; I am only asking about a rule of thumb.

Comment: Community bumps once an hour. I seldom see him more than four or five times on the front page so five or six hours should clear a batch off that page (if that is what is the concern).

Comment: (1) It's not just that edited threads are pushed to the front page - e.g. users' favourites lists are affected. (2) There's perhaps an advantage to a batch re-tagging's being recognizable as such, which it isn't if it's too spread out.

Comment: @Scortchi I don't think I understand your #1: how are favourites affected?

Comment: Recently edited posts are highlighted in your favourites list. And you may sort it by activity to see what's new.

Comment: Related question: is it better to do it at quiet times on the site, to be less disruptive (I tended to do the kernel tag cleanup late nights in US-Eastern time, after U.S. evening activity wore off and before Europe morning began), or is it actually better to do it during more active times because things are moving anyway and it won't be a huge block?

Comment: Also, I know nobody here can do anything about it, but an SE feature like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review, or simply not bumping posts on tag-only edits, would help this drastically.

Comment: @Dougal, that would be better as a new question (but note this: [When is traffic slow on CrossValidated?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/3106/7290), eg).

Comment: @Dougal I think the idea behind not editing too many questions at once is to maximize the time new questions spend on the front page. From this point of view, slow/quiet times are definitely better.

Comment: How long is a "time"?

Comment: @ssdecontrol It seems I misunderstood your question in the comment above. (Previous comment erased now). What "time" did you ask about?

Comment: You have "at a time" in a lot of the answers. What's the cooldown period you have in mind?

Comment: @ssdecontrol As written in my Q, "This assumes that "sittings" are separated by at least half a day." In general I'd say once the previous retags disappeared from the front page.

Comment: @amoeba missed that, thanks

Comment: +1. For me the main drawback of editing lots of posts at a time and bumping them to the active tab, is that it removes attention from new **answers** and posts with substantial edits. Because new questions will still be visible in the newest tab. (I had missed this post and took a good laugh when I read it :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not re-tag more than 5 old threads at a time.

Comment: So yeah that's why I never completed retagging CNN :(

Comment: I accept this answer on Sep 5. It has 7 upvotes, no-more-than-ten answer has 2 upvotes (plus my support), and no-limit answer has 6 upvotes. So 10 people prefer **limit of five to ten** while 6 people prefer no limit at all.

Comment: Update: it's now 12 vs 6.

Answer (score 7):

There is no limit. If you have the energy to re-tag 500 threads in one sitting, then thank you & Godspeed.

Comment: No reason for a limit: better tags -> better website. We should be grateful people are willing to do it free of charge. The overhead of having to come back several days or weeks in a row is unnecessary.

Comment: Agree with this, as long as the community is in agreement beforehand - such as via a meta thread discussion.

Comment: The problem with this is that people who don't participate in meta or whatever might come to ask a real question and be drowned out in the retagging noise.

Comment: Unlimited is clearly too much, IMO. 5 is mostly a reasonable, round number that shouldn't be taken too literally.

Comment: The core of the issue is that it makes no sense to bump to the front page retagged questions.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt SE admins have always said that all edits, however minor, should go to the front page for (potential) community review. But we desperately need more tools for retagging, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277076.

Answer (score 4):

Do not re-tag more than 10 old threads at a time.

Comment: I would upvote this option if I could upvote my own answer. Please count my personal vote in addition.

Answer (score 0):

Do not re-tag more than 1 old thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not re-tag more than "a couple" (2-3) old threads at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not re-tag more than 25 old threads at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not re-tag more than 50 old threads at a time.