# What's the tag "empirical" meant to convey?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization, tag-excerpt

Reading this question [How is empirical bayes valid?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/293842/how-is-empirical-bayes-valid?newsletter=1&nlcode=630151%7c9223) I thought it needed an empirical-bayes tag and so I came across the tag [empirical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empirical).

It has 98 questions tagged in really diverse topics and no excerpt or wiki.

So I ask: what's the intended usage for [empirical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empirical)?

Comment: Because tags are almost always originated by people posting questions, the only reliable way I know of figuring out the meaning of a generic-sounding tag like this is to visit numerous posts with the tag and attempt to identify what they might mean by it.

Comment: (+1) We have plenty of ambiguous, unclear, and generally useless tags. This seems to be one of them. Sorting them out is an annoying, time consuming, and thankless task.

Comment: @amoeba Well, it's certainly annoying and time consuming, but I really want to convey my thanks to you for all your efforts on improving tags -- it definitely improves the site. Often the benefits aren't clear to a casual user, but anyone who searches regularly or looks at what shows up in "Related" in the sidebar will appreciate the great importance of clear, consistent tags.

Comment: I added an answer with a proposal, please discuss under it and add criticism. Also, if anyone got a better plan altogether please add another answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the ambiguity of [empirical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empirical), I propose we get an `[empirical-bayes]` tag, and then we can retag all those questions pertaining the subject (which I volunteer to do as well).

The other questions tagged [empirical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empirical) would have it removed.

EDIT (4th August): We also have a tag [ecdf](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecdf). Some questions deserve this one, so let's try to keep it in mind.

Comment: +1 for both suggestions. I had a quick glance and could not discern any useful meaning of [empirical] apart from empirical Bayes.

Comment: @amoeba I'm doing changes 10 at a time, mostly adding the tag [tag:empirical-bayes]. I'm refraining from removing [tag:empirical] from unrelated questions for now, so if someone else brings a good reason to not proceed we can merge [tag:empirical-bayes] back into it without much loss. As you're more experienced with re-tagging, how many edits you feel start to pollute the questions field? Is 10 at a time too much?

Comment: See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4285 - the consensus opinion seems to be 5-10.

Comment: In principle there is a way to delete a tag (e.g. [empirical] after you are done tagging with empirical-bayes) but it requires mods to contact SE admins who would eradicate the tag. In practice this is never done, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3147.

Comment: Re edit: There is no [inverse-ecdf] tag. There is [inverse-cdf]. And [cdf].

Comment: @amoeba Oops, I got confused because they appear together when you type `ecdf` (i.e. "invers**e-cdf**"). Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I noticed that the tag is gone by now. Would you self-accept this answer?

Comment: Oh yeah, sure! Also, thanks for the help @amoeba!