# Should we create a [kpss-test] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

We have [augmented-dickey-fuller](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augmented-dickey-fuller) tag with 148 questions.

There are [407 questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ADF) I find when searching for ADF (Augmented Dickey Fuller).

There are [174 questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=kpss) I find when searching for KPSS (Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin).

Both the ADF Test as well as the KPSS test are tests which test whether a time series is stationary.  The Null hypothesis of the ADF test is that there is a Unit root. The Null hypothesis of the KPSS Tests is that the time series is stationary.

As KPSS test more or less the complement to the ADF test I propose to create a tag for the KPSS test as well.

More generally we could discuss the same issue for other tests, e.g. the Phillips-Perron Test.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me; without knowing I would expect that `kpss` already existed. I think it will be helpful.

Comment: Looks like you can go ahead and create this tag, if you want to.

Comment: @amoeba Okay I just created it

Comment: Please see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4285.

Comment: Don't forget to post and accept an answer in this thread stating that the tag was created!

Comment: @amoeba thank you for teaching me how this all works

Comment: Well, thank *you* for doing the job!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the [kpss-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kpss-test) tag. All questions which I consider relevant for the tag are already retagged.